# Canon D530 Laser Printer not working on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: canon, 15.04

I just upgraded to 15.04 from 14.10 and I have a new printer (Canon D530). I set it up and in the print queue it says that it printed the test page, but the printer doesn't print anything. I have the driver version 2.90.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i got the same issue with the driver 2.90 on ubuntu 14 and 15. I finally installed driver version 2.80 who is working perfectly. The driver is not available on Canon web site you have to find it in a web site listing drivers for any brands. Canon has propably broken something from release 2.80 to release 2.90.

Stephane

Comment: @Pabi: I think it's an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to where you found driver version 2.80?